# Filter Java(Android) com ParseQuery campo tipo Pointer

Tags: android, filter, parse-platform

How would I do this query, since this field (product) is of the pointer type, which references another table (group)

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryProdutos = ParseQuery.getQuery("products");
queryProdutos.whereEqualTo("group", "a431g152aa1" );
queryProdutos.findInBackground((objectGroup, e1) -> {
    for (ParseObject group: objectGroup) {
        Log.i("main", "return === " + group.getString("nome"));
    }
});
```

In NodeJS I managed to solve doing it this way:

```
.equalTo("group", { __type: 'Pointer', className: 'groups', objectId: "xxxxx" })
```

but in Java (android) I can't do it that way, I tried that way too:

```
queryProdutos.whereEqualTo("evento", new ParseObject("eventos").get(ParamsDao.getEventoId()
```

it was an attempt but it didn't work.

How to do it?

Comment: are you trying to  get another parse object from Product object?

Comment: Have you looked at  $[pt.so]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, Resolvido!

```
queryGrrupos = ParseQuery.getQuery("products");
queryGrrupos.whereEqualTo("group", ParseObject.createWithoutData("groups", ParamsDao.getEventoId()));
```